# Active X VLC Plugin Issues

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vlc

Im using a very basic ActiveX VLC Plugin. I installed VLC and then added VLC into VB.NET by going into COM Components.

So I use it to load livestreams and it works "fine".
But not great. The reason im saying this is because I load a .m3u8 file and whenever it lags/buffers/freezes/pauses e.t.c it will play again fine as I have it to "AutoLoop = true" but when it then fixes itself and continues playing it wont go Fullscreen by double clicking the Video Window and if I went into Fullscreen before it froze I would be Stuck in fullscreen and would need to ALT+F4 or ALT+TAB out and close the App.

Is there any way past this and has anyone ever encountered this issue either?
If anyone needs to try this to see what I mean or has a hard time understanding what I mean just let me know.

Comment: Still need any help as possible with this

Comment: ......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this is an error with VLC 2.2.2

It seems this is a UI issue when playback ends. The forum seems to already have a ticket open about this for 3+ months which is ridiculous that its still not fixed.

If you compile using the .dll's from VLC 2.2.2 but have VLC 2.2.1 installed on your PC then this issue is gone.